# Rollover effects on website

Tags: html, web

I have a website and will like to implement rollover popup effects on it. However, I do not wish to use javascript and flash. What other options do I have?

Comment: you can manage it with CSS3, but please don't forget that a lot people is still using browsers which doesn't support CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure css.
[Hover.css](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)

1.Include hover css file

```
<link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

2. Add classes to your element/button

```
<a href="#" class="button float">Checkout</a>
```